# What was Einstein's first publication of the final form of general relativity?

Tags: physics, reference-request, relativity-theory, einstein

What was Einstein's first published exposition of his final form of **general** relativity, be it a scientific article or a book?

I've been googling the answer for hours now, with no luck, really. The spent hours led me to think that the answer is Einstein's book (based on lectures he gave at Princeton) called *The Meaning of Relativity*, though I am far from being sure here.

His handwritten manuscripts don't count, as don't oral presentations of the theory to the Prussian Academy of Sciences (or any other oral ones).

Comment: See the book Einstein, Albert
The collected papers of Albert Einstein. Vol. 6. (German. English, German summary)
The Berlin years: writings, 1914–1917. Edited by A. J. Kox, Martin J. Klein and Robert Schulmann. Princeton University Press, Princeton, NJ, 1996. xxviii+626 pp. ISBN: 0-691-01086-2 

You will find all what you need there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1916 publication in *Annalen der Physik*, 49, 769–822, also published separately in Leipzig, see e.g. [Sauer, Albert Einstein's 1916 Review Article on General Relativity](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0405066):

> "*The first comprehensive overview of the final version of the general theory of relativity was published by Einstein in 1916 after several expositions of preliminary versions and latest revisions of the theory in November 1915.*"

This was the paper the circumstances of whose submission and publication led to the [Einstein and Hilbert priority dispute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity_priority_dispute). It was *not* his first publication on general relativity, but it added the final piece, the field equations, see [Janssen, Einstein’s First Systematic Exposition of General Relativity](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/2123/):

> "*Einstein’s first paper on a metric theory of gravity, co-authored with his mathematician friend Marcel Grossmann, was published as a separatum in early 1913 and was reprinted the following year in Zeitschrift für Mathematik und Physik (Einstein and Grossmann  1913,  1914a). Their  second  (and  last)  joint  paper  on  the  theory  also appeared in this journal (Einstein and Grossmann 1914b). Most of the formalism of general relativity as we know it today was already in place in this Einstein-Grossmann theory. Still missing were the generally-covariant Einstein field equations.*"

And Einstein vaguely pondered modifications to Newtonian gravity to reconcile them with special relativity already back in 1907, in *Über  das  Relativitätsprinzip  und  die  aus  demselben  gezogenen  Folgerungen*, *Jahrbuch der Radioaktivität und Elektronik* 4, 411–462.

Comment: Hilbert himself regarded the theory as essentially that of Einstein's; the priority dispute seems to be mostly in the eyes of commentators ...